# Match specific filename in a URL with regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm doing a huge site migration with many thousands of internal links that need to be changed to the new URL's. What I'm looking for is a regex expression where I can pass in the final part of the URL (i.e index.html) and it find that specific link in it's entirety with all sub folders etc, so that I can then replace it in the database with my new, completely different URL.

So, for example I have the OLD URL which might look like this:

http://example.com/old-folder-name/filename.html

In some cases I might also have a URL with 2, 3, 4 subfolders:

http://example.com/1/2/3/4/filename.html

I need to search by just the filename and return the entire URL so I can replace it in the DB.

I'm absolutely useless with regular expression. I can match the filename easy enough, but i'm not able to figure out how to search the filename and select the entire URL ready for replacing.

Comment: There are many questions that answer how to make a regexp that matches a URL. Take one of them, and just change it to end with `/filename.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many regex's out there for intricate URI matching, but this will capture URLs starting with "http" and ending with the "filename.html" you are searching for.

```
/(http.+filename\.html)/gi
```

Testing: https://regex101.com/

Comment: This works perfectly in the testing tools, but for some reason none of the regex plugins for WordPress are able to find a match. I'll mark it as the answer though, because it does work.

Comment: Wordpress, regex plugins... this is new info. Which one are you using?

Comment: I tried both the Broken Link Checker plugin, which has a regex option, and also Search Regex (https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/). The pattern returns no results in each of them.

Comment: Ah, ok, try this and see: `(http.+filename\.html)`, and check case-insensitive and multi-line, using search-regex